# Why was my question edit to add a tag for the library used rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The question I am talking about is located here: [Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Alea.dll "i32 is not struct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330186/exception-thrown-system-exception-in-alea-dll-i32-is-not-struct-type)

The only tag on it when I saw it was the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag. The OP confirmed in the comments that the issue he was experiencing originated in a function call used from the [Alea GPU](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/gpu_programming_csharp.html) library, and we have an existing tag for it: [aleagpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aleagpu). To me, it made sense to add this tag in a suggested edit to better attract attention from those knowledgeable about the library, who might understand where that issue is coming from.

The suggested edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16308737) by two people, one who said it did not help the post at all and the other saying it deviated from the author's intent. I am not understanding the reasoning here behind those rejection reasons, so I was hoping somebody could clarify what exactly was wrong with my suggested change.

Comment: Meh, people reject stuff all the time. In this case, there were some other things that you could have done to improve the question (cleaning up the tile, correcting grammar ["and why am I getting it"], etc.). I probably would have hit Improve Edit and done it myself, but that's me. Honestly, you'd have to ask them...

Comment: *The OP confirmed in the comments that the issue he was experiencing originated in a function call used from the Alea GPU library* - We can't see user comments in the review queue. The 3rd reviewer probably thought you were just adding a random tag since the post itself doesn't mention that library at all. If you're fixing a post based on something posted in the comments section, that has to be in your edit summary.

Comment: As for the other issues you didn't fix, not everyone agrees on how much a user has to fix to warrant "Improve and Edit" instead of "Reject and Edit". The safest thing to do is to fix everything. (Not everyone agrees you should have to but if all you miss is a period or a capitalization you're much less likely to get a reject.)

Comment: TBH, If you hadn't pointed it out, I would have gone "that's a jumbled mess of letters for a tag...wat" and rejected it

Comment: I'm one of the reviewers who rejected it. I saw error messages that could have been formatted and a typo that could have been fixed, and the only change was an added tag, so I rejected it as not an improvement. In hindsight, it seems kind of strict considering how minor the other improvements could be, but I feel that if you're going to edit a post, you should try to fix everything.

Comment: I edited the question and also added the tag. But still the question is of borderline quality.

Comment: The funny thing is that nobody bothered in editing the things that were the reasons why your edit was rejected.

Comment: not related to the question at hand but i feel that tag should have a `-` in it to make it `alea-gpu` as that makes it easier to read

Comment: @Jeeter if you don't recognize a tag the first thing you should do is check the tag out. Then you can make an informed decision on whether to approve the edit or skip the edit. Gut-rejecting because you don't recognize a tag is no better than robo-reviewing, and is therefore bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [BSMP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4076315/bsmp) said [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350144/why-was-my-question-edit-to-add-a-tag-for-the-library-used-rejected/350225?noredirect=1#comment478697_350144), the OP confirmed in the comments that the issue he was experiencing originated in a function call used from the Alea GPU library - We can't see user comments in the review queue.

The 3rd reviewer probably thought you were just adding a random tag since the post itself doesn't mention that library at all. If you're fixing a post based on something posted in the comments section, that has to be in your edit summary.

Comment: @Enzokie Done :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's just a (not very clear) way of giving credit to the comments on this question for his source.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Bothered to click the link or to check where it refers to? Hint: its a comment.

Comment: @Tom: There's no need for sarcasm. Yes, I did, but not quite in that way. I thought Damith was referring to another question, which would make this a duplicate, so I went through the duplicates process (looking to read the target when it popped up), and that's when I noticed it was the same question. And yeah, the link is **really** unclear. *(Edit: I've fixed it now.)*